# Cakephp 3 NGINX URL rewriting issue

Tags: cakephp, nginx, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to setup CakePHP 3 on Linux server CentOS 7 OS. I have created a project using composer and everything installs correctly with proper permissions. In my virtual host file I have configured config file according to [official document](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#nginx)

```
server {
      listen      80;
      server_name remote.inodd.com;
      ## redirect http to https ##
      rewrite 301 https://$server_name$request_uri permanent;
      #rewrite  301 https://$server_name$request_uri permanent;
}

server {
#    listen       80;
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  remote.inodd.com;
    ssl_certificate /home/vhost/www/domain/ssl/self-ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/vhost/www/domain/ssl/self-ssl.key;

    # note that these lines are originally from the "location /" block
    root   /home/vhost/www/domain/public_html;
    index index.php;
    access_log /home/vhost/www/domain/logs/access_log;
    error_log /home/vhost/www/domain/logs/error_log;

    location / {
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?url=$request_uri;
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

so when I browse the url https://remote.inodd.com/development/, I get default landing page showing status of cakephp configuration. Everything checks out normal even database connectivity. But I get below warning that rewriting is not configured correctly.

URL rewriting is not properly configured on your server.

1) Help me configure it

2) I don't / can't use URL rewriting

Not sure what else I am missing here as I am able to setup non-cakephp sites and they are working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working. Thanks to a great solution provided by [Jamie](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/989732/Are-You-Having-CakePHP-and-NGINX-Rewrite-Rule-Issu).

Here is my final working code:

```
server {
      listen      80;
      server_name remote.inodd.com;
      ## redirect http to https ##
      rewrite        ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
#       listen   80;
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  remote.inodd.com;
    ssl_certificate /home/vhost/www/domain/ssl/self-ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/vhost/www/domain/ssl/self-ssl.key;
    access_log /home/vhost/www/domain/logs/access_log;
    error_log /home/vhost/www/domain/logs/error_log;

        location / {
                root   /home/vhost/www/domain/public_html/development/webroot;
                index  index.php index.html index.htm;

                if (-f $request_filename) {
                        break;
                }

                if (-d $request_filename) {
                        break;
                }
                rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
        }

        location ~ .*\.php[345]?$ {
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index   index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME
                /home/vhost/www/domain/public_html/development/webroot$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your domain has a conf file in vhost then please add this line to your vhost domain.conf file.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
    rewrite ^/$ /app/webroot/ break;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /app/webroot/$1 break;

}
location /app/ {
    rewrite ^/$ /webroot/ break;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /webroot/$1 break;
}
location /app/webroot/ {
    if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php break;
    }
}
```

The main problem is cakephp has 3 different htaccess, 
first is the main dir of project
second one is in app folder
third is webroot folder.
So we have to handle all of this. I found a solution like that.